# Creating Spotify keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, spotify

I'm on Windows 10 64 bit, Using spotify desktop free version. Is there a way to create keyboard Spotify shortcuts to pause/play and skip tracks, while outside Spotify? I don't want to keep opening it. I might be browsing or coding, I need quick shortcuts.

Comment: Hey Spotify, make `Enter` when hovering over a song **play a song** instead of save it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [Toastify](https://toastify.codeplex.com/). From the website: "Toastify adds some missing functionallity to the Spotify client(Windows only). It shows a popup, toast style, dialog on track change and it allows you to use global hot keys for Play/Pause, Next, Previous etc." I've used it before to add hotkeys in Windows 7 and 8, works pretty well.

Comment: Partially working for me.

Comment: I get an error with Toastify when I open link in Chrome... "The site ahead contains harmful programs. Attackers on archive.codeplex.com might attempt to trick you into installing programs that harm your browsing experience (for example, by changing your homepage or showing extra ads on sites that you visit)."

Comment: Same here. Not worth the risk!

Answer (score 28):

This feature has already [been requested](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Global-HotKey-for-Pause-Play-Next-Song-etc/idi-p/57061/), and Spotify developers have manifested their lack of interest in adding it in the near future:

> Hey everyone, Spotify Staff here. We wanted to update this idea as it's continued to gain kudos. Right now we don't have any plans to implement this so we're marking it as 'Not Right Now'.

However, you can still solve it with third party softare, like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Once you have installed it, you only have to add a script like the following:

```
!Left::Media_Prev
!Right::Media_Next
!DOWN::Media_Play_Pause
```

This will assign the following shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→ (right arrow)</kbd> to skip to the next song
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>← (left arrow)</kbd> to go to the previous song
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓ (down arrow)</kbd> to play/pause the currently playing song

Of course, you can modify the script to fit your key preferences. More info about that in AutoKotkey [docs](https://autohotkey.com/docs).

The benefits of this is that it will work with other media playing programs, such as VLC or Windows Media Player, because they trigger the OS's media keys.

Comment: This is unnecessary if your keyboard already got media keys!

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use AutoHotkey for the **Add to My Music** functionality? Since it is not a menu option in the Spotify app I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/ also has key remapping functionality now :)