# Keyboard control of Groove

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, groove-music

I'm using Groove, the Windows 10 music player.  It's good, I don't want to download another.  I use Spotify but for my local music, I use Groove.

I was wondering if:

- It can be minimized to tray
- I could control it using the keyboard, such as AutoHotKey associations or something, to play, pause, etc.

Comment: submit the requests in the feedback hub app, MS does't listen here for requests.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because superuser.com is not the correct place for requesting new features to Microsoft apps. Use the feedback hub app of Windows 10 to request new features and send feedback.

Comment: @magicandre1981 im not requesting for features from ms, im seeking third party solutions  like http://superuser.com/questions/1070156/creating-spotify-keyboard-shortcuts and http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/alternatives-to-sticky-notes-that-doesnt-use-the-taskbar `someone`'s answer - but a different program since his is a malware probably

Comment: @magicandre1981 wondering about third party solutions, such as AutoHotKey, I've been asking such questions since forever and there are tons of other questions, none have been closed. Why the change of heart today? If I get answers millions will benefit since groove is the main music player on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite likely you can implement both of those features in AutoHotkey.

For minimize-to-tray you could make a tray icon that effectively shows/hides the Groove window (which would make it look like Groove got minimized to the tray).  See `WinShow` and `WinHide` commands.

For controlling via keyboard you could likely use `ControlSend` commands to directly send keystrokes to Groove to control playback, even if it isn't visible or active.  There is also a WinAmp example in the AutoHotkey help files that utilized window messages if I recall correctly (see help for `SendMessage`--whether Groove uses that type of interface I have no idea)

Maybe I will look at it at it on a Win10 machine sometimes... haven't used it myself but I'm pretty sure you could get it to do something like that.